# java - scanner only allow defined strings

Tags: java

I want to read in an operator through user input with a scanner. The scanner should read in the input as long as a pre-defined operator is typed in. I thought it would work like this, but it returns `command cannot be resolved` in the while part.

```
String [] operators = new String [3];
operators[0] ="!";
operators[1] ="&&";
operators[2] ="||";

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
System.out.println("Command: ");

do {
String command = sc.next();
} while(!command.equals(operators[0]) || !command.equals(operators[1]) || !command.equals(operators[2]));
```

Comment: `command` is declared in the scope of your `while` block, and evaluated outside it. Also, for what value of `sc.next()` will your `while` statement evaluate to false?

Comment: I misunderstood your question because of the word "returns". Your code here does not "return" anything. Instead, it is more correct to say that you get a compiler error. I hope this helps you learn some terminology so that you can ask questions more clearly in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare `command` outside the `do-while` loop because if you declare any variable inside `do-while` loop, it's scope will be limited to the body of the `do-while` loop. It won't be accessible outside the loop's body.

```
String [] operators = new String [3];
operators[0] ="!";
operators[1] ="&&";
operators[2] ="||";
String command;

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        
System.out.println("Command: ");

do {
    command = sc.next();
} while(!command.equals(operators[0]) || !command.equals(operators[1]) || !command.equals(operators[2]));
```

Comment: Can you tell me why it is not continuing to run the code like this, but when I use exclusive or in the while part? Like that it just keeps reading in

Comment: @JacobBalb you need to use `&&` operator instead of `||` operator.